# Twitter Stream API Data Structure

Tags: php, json, api, twitter, stream

I wonder are there any documentation or APIs about Twitter Stream API response JSON structures?

There is info about stream response code but there are no docs about how to read JSON structures.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

you could use json_decode to convert it to a php-array or read it using jquery and dump it to the front-end. From there on you will probably have to figure out yourself how the object is build and which items you need an store/output the content the way you like

Comment: Already did it. But it is very complex and I want to pick up right data :). An official or semi-official doc will be great.